# Find gradient from complicated objective function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gradient

I have a problem in calculating symbolic gradient from the following objective function:

```
syms x
gradient(@objfun,x)


function f = objfun(x)

N = 4;
I = 3;
fr = 5;

f_temp = 0;
for n=1:N
    sum2 = 0;
    for i=1:I
        sum1 = fr*(1 - x(n+((i-1)*N)));
        sum2 = sum2 + sum1;  
    end
    f_temp = f_temp + sum2;
end

f = 100*f_temp;                
end
```

However, this error appears "Only anonymous functions and functions without arguments can be converted to sym". How to make this code works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gradient` function takes a symbolic expression as input, not a function pointer. MATLAB's complaining because it's trying to convert your function pointer to a symbolic expression and it can't.

In this case the following works

```
N = 4; I = 3;
x = sym('x',[N,I]);     % Define a matrix of symbolic variables
f = objfun(x);          % Get symbolic expression for objfun in terms of x
```

*Disclaimer* This works because all the operations in `objfun` are supported on symbolic variables. For more complex objective functions this approach may not work.

This defines `x` as a `N`-by-`I` matrix of symbolic variables

```
>> x
x =
[ x1_1, x1_2, x1_3]
[ x2_1, x2_2, x2_3]
[ x3_1, x3_2, x3_3]
[ x4_1, x4_2, x4_3]
```

and defines `f` as

```
>> f
f = 
6000 - 500*x1_2 - 500*x1_3 - 500*x2_1 - 500*x2_2 - 500*x2_3 - 500*x3_1 - 500*x3_2 - 500*x3_3 - 500*x4_1 - 500*x4_2 - 500*x4_3 - 500*x1_1
```

Then we find the gradient of `f` with respect `x` to be

```
>> g = reshape(gradient(f,x(:)), size(x))
g =
[ -500, -500, -500]
[ -500, -500, -500]
[ -500, -500, -500]
[ -500, -500, -500]
```

The extra `reshape` is to conform to the common interpretation for the gradient as a tensor with the same dimensions as `x`.

**Edit**
To respond to the comment. If you want to use this with `fmincon` so that you have a function which gives both the objective value and gradient then you can construct such a function handle as follows.

```
grad_fun = matlabFunction(g,'Vars',x);
obj_with_grad = @(x) deal(objfun(x), grad_fun(x));
```

Now you can get the objective and gradient at any point. For example at x=ones(N,I);

```
>> [obj_val, grad_val] = obj_with_grad(ones(N,I))
obj_val =
      0
grad_val =
  -500  -500  -500
  -500  -500  -500
  -500  -500  -500
  -500  -500  -500
```

I didn't test, but you should be able to use `obj_with_grad` with `fmincon` now by setting `fmincon`'s `'SpecifyObjectiveGradient'` option to `true`.

Comment: do you have idea to make x1_1 to x(1,1)? I want to use this gradient for optimization solver thus I need x(1) instead of x1.

Comment: You can make x whatever size you want. I made it `N` by `I` to match your indexing scheme. In your objfun `x` just needs to have at least `N*I` entries. Change the declaration of `x` to `x = sym('x', [N*I, 1]);` to make `x` a column vector.

Comment: What I mean is the gradient result show like x1, x2, x3. Do you have any solution to make them as x(1), x(2), x(3) (with additional bracket) without changing manually since I use these variables on fmincon? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can turn the expression into a function handle with `matlabFunction` if that's what you're asking. I.e. `grad_fun = matlabFunction(g,'Vars',x);` There's no built-in way to add the parenthesis to the string representation AFAIK.

Comment: @bnbfreak I updated the answer to provide details on my last comment.